# Android Home button click ignoring saved state?

Tags: android, android-homebutton

Can I ignore the previous stage of application after tapping Home button in android?
So that I can get the application from initial screen.

Comment: Previous statge,are you meaning previous activity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use like this.If now you are in LastActivity and you want to go back to the First Activity and there is more activity in between then if you want to go first from last use

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(autoSearch)
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
           Log.d("click","HOMEButtonclicked");
          LastActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(LastActivity.this, FirstActivity.class));
           moveTaskToBack(false);
           return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```